# Switching between DNS addresses easily

Tags: windows, dns, tcpip

Sometimes I need to use preferred and alternate DNS server addresses, and sometimes I need Windows to obtain it automatically. The common approach to switch between those addresses is:

- Right click on `Local Area Connection` icon on the taskbar notification area
- Select `Status`
- Click on `Properties`
- Select `Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)` and select `Properties`
- Switch between `Obtain DNS server address automatically` and `Use the following DNS server addresses`.

Since I am switching them frequently, I need a faster and easier way to do this. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `netsh.exe` command-line utility to achieve that. I found [this page](https://petri.com/configure_tcp_ip_from_cmd) which provides some examples, including a couple to edit nameservers.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Net Profiles](http://code.google.com/p/netprofiles/) for this purpose. You can make predefined network profiles and easily switch between them at any time:

[image]

> **Features**
>
> - Save your network settings as profiles.
> - Automatically activate wireless profiles when specified wireless
>     connections are detected. (XP only)
> - **Change IP Address, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway, Primary and Secondary
>     DNS Servers, WINS Server, and DHCP
>     settings with the click of a button.**
> - Specifiy different mapped drives for each profile.
> - Change your default printer based on which profile you're currently using.
> - Automatically change your profile via program shortcuts created with Net
>     Profiles.
> - Change the default homepage for Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera.
> - Proxy settings for Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Opera.
> - Run a user-defined list of programs when a profile is activated.
> - Maintain seperate desktop wallper for each profile.
> - Change screen resolutions and color quality when profiles are activated.
> - Can be easily translated into other languages using the enclosed XML
>     language file.

Net Profiles is free and open source.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) script to change the DNS settings as shown in [this blog](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2007/10/10/powershell-script-to-update-dns-search-order-on-a-particular-nic-on-multiple-remote-machines.aspx):

```
$strDNSServers = "192.168.1.50", "192.168.1.51","192.168.1.52"

function Update-DNS
{
  $Nic = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -comp $strComputer |where{$_.NetConnectionID -eq "Local Area Connection"}

  $Config   = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -comp $strComputer |where{$_.MACAddress -eq $Nic.MACAddress}

  write-host "The current DNS Search Order is:"
  $config.DNSServerSearchOrder

  $config.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($strDNSServers) | out-null
}
```